# nohup - permission denied

Tags: shell, nohup

I am trying to get a start up script for OrientDB (a database) on Ubuntu to work.

This is currently the line that causes problems:

```
ORIENTDB_DIR="/usr/local/orientdb"
ORIENTDB_USER="www-user"
sudo -u $ORIENTDB_USER sh -c "cd \"$ORIENTDB_DIR/bin\"; /usr/bin/nohup server.sh 1>../log/orientdb.log 2>../log/orientdb.err &"
```

If I start the script, it results in this:

```
sh: 1: cannot create ../log/orientdb.log: Permission denied
```

Here's the setup:

- `www-user` is in the sudoers file
- `server.sh` and any the shell script posted above have execute privileges for root.
- If I change the script to this:
  `sudo -u $ORIENTDB_USER sh -c "cd \"$ORIENTDB_DIR/bin\"; /usr/bin/nohup pwd 1>/home/www-user/test.log &"`, `test.log` shows `/usr/local/orientdb/bin/` as the working directory.
- `/usr/local/orientdb/log` exists but is an empty folder.

Given the above and the fact that I am using `sudo` to elevate the user, why is permission still denied?

Comment: `sudo` doesn't always elevate a user. `sudo` changes the user, most commonly to `root`, but you're changing it to `www-user`, which may be less privileged than your current user.

Comment: @icktoofay: After creating `www-user`, I added him to sudoers: `usermod -aG sudo www-user`. This means that `www-user` can sudo into `root`, right?

Comment: Well, that depends on your `sudo` configuration. Probably, yes. But that's not what I was trying to say. I was saying that `sudo` with `-u` does not elevate to `root` — instead, it switches to that user. If you instead want to change to `root`, leave off the `-u` and its argument.

Comment: If I leave off `-u username`, I still see the permission denied error. Hmm....

Comment: What if you run `ls -ld /usr/local/orientdb/log`?

Comment: @icktoofay: The folder is owned by root: `drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 11 10:13 /usr/local/orientdb/log`.

Comment: @icktoofay: After a restart and `-u username`, I no longer get a permission denied message, which was odd. In any case, please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept :)

Comment: I meant to say: "After a restart and leaving off `-u username`". Hope that clears things up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have been misunderstanding `sudo` a bit — `sudo` does not necessarily elevate a user's rights; in fact, it may reduce the rights they have. When you pass `sudo` the `-u` flag, it will change to that user. If that user has more rights — `root`, for example (the default if `-u` is not passed) — then you'll get more rights. If the user has less rights — `nobody`, for example — you'll have less rights. You said that the `log` directory has these permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 11 10:13 /usr/local/orientdb/log
```

Yet, you're changing to the `www-user` user. The `www-user` user, unless it is part of the `root` group (unlikely), will not be able to write to that directory: it is only writable by the owner and group, and `www-user` is clearly not the `root` user and `www-user` is probably not part of the `root` group.

In short, don't pass `-u` (and its associated argument) if you want to elevate to `root`.

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting the last line of your script to:

```
sudo -u $ORIENTDB_USER sh -c "/usr/bin/nohup \"$ORIENTDB_DIR\"/bin/server.sh 1> \"$ORIENTDB_DIR\"/log/orientdb.log 2> \"$ORIENTDB_DIR\"/log/orientdb.err &"
```

If that still doesn't work, then `www-user` probably doesn't have write permission to `/usr/local/orientdb/log` (Note that you said `/usr/local/orientdb/logs` exists but is an empty folder: one of them has a `s` at the end)

Comment: My apologies, the folder is `log` and not `logs` :) Having said that, after I used your change, I am still seeing permission denied: `sh: 1: cannot create /usr/local/orientdb/log/orientdb.log: Permission denied`